# laravel select 5 random rows from the 20 most recent rows ( without mapping after load & do with one query )

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

how I can do this

Ex: select 5 random rows from the 20 most recent row

I need to do this with eloquent and get data with a query from DB not with mapping data

I found this query but I can't convert this to laravel eloquent …

Query :

select tbl1.* from (select *from DemoTable ORDER BY ShippingDate DESC LIMIT 20 ) as tbl1
-> ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;

Comment: refer : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/eloquent-take-25-random-out-of-400-first-rows-laravel-52

Comment: something like this maybe `Model::all()->take(20)->get()->random(5);`

Comment: Tnx , but This is not my answer , this cide use mapping adter get all rowa , and i need do this with one query from server

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code. Change Models and columns for your models and columns. I wrote a user for the test

```
return User::query()
->whereIn('id', function($query)
{
   $query->from('users')
    ->selectRaw('id')
    ->orderByDesc('created_at')->limit(20);
})->inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();
```

if you get toSql() you see

```
select * from `users` where `id` in (select id from `users` order by `created_at` desc limit 20) limit 5
```

Comment: But that code doesn't return random rows. You shoud use random(5) instead of limit(5)

Comment: @Tiago Edited answer